# Wrong titlebar text

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

I assume the `<title>` of the page should be "Ask Different" instead of "Apple", since that's how [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually incorrect.

We don't make that change except in the rare case where the URL is formally something other than

> topic.stackexchange.com

That is why you will see it on http://askubuntu.com -- but not http://cooking.stackexchange.com which has an alias of http://seasonedadvice.com.

That said the alias

## http://askdifferent.com

should work to get you here!